how to add custom module in apps of shopware 6
I want to add Custom module in shopware 6 through apps. It is showing error and also not showing module in my app.
<admin>
        <module name="normalModule"
                source="\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\var\www\sw6\custom\apps\TestExample\Resources\app\administration\src\module\mainModule"
                parent="sw-catalogue"
                position="50"
        >
            <label>Module in admin menu</label>
            <label lang="de-DE">Modul im Adminmenü</label>
        </module>

         <main-module source="https://sw6.local/main"/>
</admin>

